# Likelihood of an outcome happening at least $n$ times in $x$ tries when the probability is known using normal approximation

Tags: probability, approximation

So, I have a sample size of $220$, and I'm trying to use normal approximation to calculate the minimum amount of times the outcome $A$ is expected to happen at $99$%. In other words, I'm interested in knowing the breakpoint where the likelihood for $A$ happening $x$ or less times is, at most, 1%.

Through the power of cheating I know that the correct answer is $40$, but I'm trying to understand how it's actually calculated. The 40 would mean "the minimum amount of times $A$ happens at 99% probability" or in other words "The probability Not $A$ happening ($220-40=180$) times is 1% or less"

Here's an example question if what I'm trying to calculate was confusing:

An airline that has 220 passengers traveling knows that 25% of the passengers never show up. They want to calculate how many seats the airplane they use for the flight has to have so that the likelihood of not having enough seats for the passengers that do show up is, at most, 1%.

Comment: On rereading, I think I misread the question.  You want a number, presumably less than $220$, of seats an airplane might have in order to accommodate the supposed $220$ passengers?  Where does $40$ come in?  That is far too few seats.

Comment: The 40 is for the initial question, it would hold for the example if the passenger no-show rate was 5% instead of 25%.

If the passenger no-show rate was 40, then the 40 would be "minimum amount of passengers that would be no-shows at 99% certainty" or in other words "the likelihood of more than 180 passengers showing up is 1% or less"

The example initially had 5% instead of 25% because I thought I should make a more generic example but I realize that it was confusing so I changed it to 25%

Comment: Well, I don't see how $40$ could possibly be the answer to the original question, so I expect I am still reading it incorrectly.  If a randomly selected person shows up with probability $p$ then the probability that exactly $k$ people show up is $\binom {220}k\times p^k\times (1-p)^{220-k}$.  It's easy to compute this and add them up.  With $p=.75$ we see that the probability that $≥180$ people show up is $0.010167364$ which, I think is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I guess I just worded it poorly. I was talking about the inverse of that where 40 would be "not p"

Comment: Well, I still don't understand the question.  Still, whatever it is you are asking, I expect that the binomial distribution can easily be used to answer it.  Good luck.